# How to measure with ALLSELECTED function but filtering with the columns in a visual table

Tags: powerbi, dax

My question is very simple, how can I use the function ALLSELECTED ignoring one column?

The table where I'm trying to make the measures is the following example,

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1sg.png)

I have build a visual table and inserted a visual filter as well, with a simple SUM of the "realizado" number,

[Visual 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZxo.png)

I have duplicated this visual table and inserted my measure instead of the simple SUM,

I want to get the same result (4.585) for the month over the column in the visual, whenever I press the filter, because I want to discover the % of that value "Armador", over the total of others values "Armador", just for the specific month,

[Expected example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCFXF.png)